# How can I force my HTML file to search outside of it's folder?

Tags: css, html

My HTML file will only search in its own folder for my CSS file that I have linked in another folder. How do I force it to search the other folder?

I have my html file in a folder titled INDEX and my css file in a folder titled STYLE. Whenever I run the html file, the google element inspection tool shows that the html file always searches in the INDEX folder, no matter how many folders I go back.

```
<title>Seb's Portfolio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebDev/Portfolio/style/style.css">
```

I expect the html to look in the folder I specified but it keeps looking in its own folder.

This is what the google inspect tool outputs with the error message:

file:///C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/WebDev/Portfolio/index/style/style.css
no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Why do you have your HTML file in it's own folder? Your href path seems incorrect with your current setup. Have you tried `../style/style.css` instead? I'm making the assumption your `index` folder is in `Portfolio`.

Comment: That's how I was told to do it in school. My professor explained that the best way to maintain an organized project is to hold the index in its own file and the css in a separate file. Your solution worked but I have no idea why and I have no idea why it was different from what I put.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css">`

The reason yours didn't work:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebDev/Portfolio/style/style.css">`

In your code, you have this in your index.html file, which is in your `index` folder. So the href is trying to look for `WebDev/Portfolio/style/style.css` INSIDE your `index` folder.

The reason why the solution works, is that you are saying start in my `index` folder, then look outside of the `index` folder for the `style` folder and get the `style.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question your folder structure is like

```
index - index.html  
style - style.css
```

In order to reference style.css from your index folder you need to do use `../` (go up a folder):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.css">
```

Comment: This worked. Why didn't my code for it to go up a level on it's own if I referenced the folder so far back?

Comment: Because the path you provide is what is called relative and hereby relative to your index.html file

Answer (score 0):

When linking a stylesheet in html, the `href` tag is always from the scope of the file that has that tag, when using relative file paths.

Assuming that the `INDEX` folder and the `STYLE` folders are located in the same folder/directory, when linking the `style.css` in the `index.html` you want to *first* go up one directory (to the folder containing both the `INDEX` and `STYLE` folders) and then link the `style.css` from the `STYLE` folder.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../STYLE/style.css">`

[Here's some further reading on file paths in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought the path was automatically established when you referenced a folder earlier in the directory.